# Children ref undefined react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a component wrapper around **ViewPagerAndroid** (simplified version)

```
class TabView extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { position: 0 }
    }

    changePage = (key) => { 
        this._pagerRef.setPage(key)
        this.setState({position: key})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ViewPagerAndroid ref={(ref) => this._pagerRef = ref}>
                 { this.props.scenes }
            </ViewPagerAndroid>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to trigger `changePage` from outside the component (eg from: `<TabView ref={(ref) => this._ref = ref} />`, and run `this._ref.changePage(key)`).

However, each time I try to do so, `this._pagerRef` is undefined inside the `changePage` function of **TabView**.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Is the `ViewPagerAndroid ref` callback ever called? Is it called with a valid ref value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more idiomatic React solution to the problem you are trying to solve -- namely making `TabView` a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and setting ViewPager page on `componentDidUpdate`:

```
class TabView extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate = ({ page }) => {
    // call setPage if page has changed
    if (page !== this.props.page && this._pagerRef) {
      this._pagerRef.setPage(page);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ViewPagerAndroid
        initialPage={this.props.page}
        ref={ref => this._pagerRef = ref}
        onPageSelected={e => this.props.pageChanged(e.nativeEvent.position)}
      >
        {this.props.scenes}
      </ViewPagerAndroid>
    );
  }
}
```

You can then move the current page tracking to the parent component's state and pass it down to `TabView` as a prop, along with a handler that updates it when the value changes:

```
render() {
  return (
    <TabView 
      page={this.state.page} 
      pageChanged={page => this.setState({page})}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the `ref` from *outside of the component* which has no instance to it.

Therefore you need to pass it as a `prop` from the parent component itself. Also you need to move the `changePage` to the parent component to access it from outside.

**Parent**

```
 changePage = (key) => {   //... Call the function here
    this._pagerRef.setPage(key)
    this.setState({position: key})
}

 accessRef (ref) {
     this._pagerRef = ref .  //... Bind the ref here
 } 

 <TabView passRef={this.accessRef} /> //...Pass the ref here
```

**Child**

```
<ViewPagerAndroid ref={this.props.passRef}> . // ... Set the ref here
                 { this.props.scenes }
            </ViewPagerAndroid>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd feel about this solution if someone suggested it in my project. Leaking refs to parents feels a bit dirty and couples the parent to the particular implementation of TabView.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I’ll try to explore it a bit more.